# OSX application freezes when try to set the value of TextView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am really new to Objective-C.

First please see the code:

Here it is the property:

```
@property (atomic) IBOutlet NSTextView *txtResponse;
```

And here it is the action:

```
- (IBAction)sendReq:(id)sender {
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        request *req = [[request alloc] init];

        voidCallback callback = ^(NSURLResponse *resp,  NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            NSString *val = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            [self.txtResponse setString:val];
            //NSLog(val);
        };

        [req setUrl:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://foo.bar"]];

        [req setCallback:callback];

        [req send];
    }
}
```

The UI freezes when I try to use `[self.txtResponse setString:val];`
I also tried the code without `@synchronized(self)`
Where is the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure `val` is not nil? Try print it before you set it to the text view.

Comment: Does it freeze without @synchronize?  I ask because it sounds like you are encountering a deadlock.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer Yes, I used `NSLog` to show the content

Comment: @Jeremy Yes it does. I used also thread lock but it doesn't helped :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3rd day that I am working with objective-c and finally found the answer :)

I used the `performSelectorOnMainThread` and solved the problem

```
- (IBAction)sendReq:(id)sender {

    request *req = [[request alloc] init];

    voidCallback callback = ^(NSURLResponse *resp,  NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSString *val = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setResponseValue:) withObject:val waitUntilDone:NO];
    };

    [req setUrl:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://programming.com"]];

    [req setCallback:callback];

    [req send];
}

- (void)setResponseValue:(NSString *)resp
{
    [self.txtResponse setString:resp];
    //NSLog(resp);
}
```

Comment: Slightly better is `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });` from within the block (no need for an intermediate method).

Comment: @trojanfoe Please answer completely instead of a little comment :)